# Divide objects into parts

Tags: permutations

I want to divide x distinct objects in some specified groups..
Lets say 3 groups of a,b,c number of 
I am able to find when objects are similar but not in this case.

Comment: Please elaborate.Can't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Here $a+b+c=x$

Case 1: $a,b,c$ are pairwise unequal.

Choose $a$ elements for the first group from $x$ elements at first in ${x \choose a}$ ways. Then choose $b$ elements for the second group from the rest elements in ${x-a \choose b}$ ways . Remaining are the $c$ elements for the 3rd group.So the total no. of choices are ${x \choose a}{x-a \choose b}$

case 2: Only two of $a,b,c$ are equal.Let W.L.O.G $a=b$

Choose $a$ elements for the first group from $x$ elements at first in ${x \choose a}$ ways. Then choose $b=a$ elements for the second group from the rest elements in ${x-a \choose a}$ ways . Remaining are the $c$ elements for the 3rd group. So the no. of choices are ${x \choose a}{x-a \choose a}$. But in this case we have to divide this by $2!$(why?) to get the total no. of choices.So total no. of choices are $\frac12{x \choose a}{x-a \choose a}$

case 3: $a=b=c$

Choose $a$ elements for the first group from $x$ elements at first in ${x \choose a}$ ways. Then choose $b=a$ elements for the second group from the rest elements in ${x-a \choose a}$ ways . Remaining are the $c$ elements for the 3rd group. So the no. of choices are ${x \choose a}{x-a \choose a}$. But in this case we have to divide this by $3!$(why?) to get the total no. of choices.So total no. of choices are $\frac1{3!}{x \choose a}{x-a \choose a}$